# How do I use the max function in Python?

Tags: python, django

```
num = request.GET.get("num",20)
```

By default, the num is 20. But, if the user passes in 100, how can I set num to 50? (the max that I allow?)

Comment: What did you try?  Did you an `if` statement yet?

Comment: If you want to trim down a number, you should use `min` rather than `max`.

Comment: If you're having trouble with max, then you're not ready to be using an ORM.  (You're a bit of an enigma: this is a very novice question for someone who's asked over 800 questions...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you should use `min` rather than `max`:

```
num = int(request.GET.get("num", 20))
num = min(num, 50)
```

Comment: Funny how this is subtly broken: min("100", 50) == 50 == min("15", 50).

Answer (score 7):

Just add one more line:

```
num = int(request.GET.get("num", 20))
if num > 50:
    num = 50
```

Or, if you want to use `min` you could write:

```
# "num" parameter assumed to be convertable to an `int`
num = min(int(request.GET.get("num", 20)), 50)
```